# Building Strings for a HashSet in Java - Unable to Loop correctly through large string

Tags: java, stringbuilder, hashset

I am attempting to extract words as strings out of one very long string that contains many words. I'm trying to take this big blob of a string, move through it with a for loop, building strings as I go, adding them to the hashset, and keeping track of how many words I have in the process. I was so proud out myself when I had everything built and eclipse wasn't showing any obvious errors, then when I went to test it I had a 0 counter, 0 hashset.size and an empty hashset :(

Here is the code I've been fudging with:

```
    public int countUniqueWords(String line) {
    hashset = new HashSet<String>();
    word = new StringBuilder();
    int endOfLine = line.length() - 1;
    boolean isWord = false;
    String stringWord = null;
    Integer counter = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++) {
        if (Character.isLetter(line.charAt(i)) == true && i != endOfLine) {
            word.append(line.charAt(i));
        } else if (Character.isLetter(line.charAt(i)) == false && isWord == true) {
            counter++;
            stringWord = word.toString();
            hashset.add(stringWord);
            word = null;
            isWord = false;
        } else if (Character.isLetter(line.charAt(i)) && i == endOfLine) {
            counter++;
            stringWord = word.toString();
            hashset.add(stringWord);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(counter);
    System.out.println(hashset.size());
    System.out.println(hashset);
    return counter;
}
```

I will continue to search and kick the tires. In the meantime, if anyone has any suggestions I will reward you with lots of mental good vibes over here in my little home office. It seems like there are at least one or two very fundamental errors I am making here, because obviously it's not even iterating through the loop like it's supposed to. I suspect it has something to do with me using StringBuilder together with HashSets and the Character class, all mashed together while not understanding any of these particularly well. And yes, I've poured over the oracle docs.

Comment: Why don't you just use `String[] words = line.split(" ")` or similar to know the words in the `line`? After that, you can _clean_ every `words[index]` by removing any other non-letter characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first condition is true for all characters

```
   if (Character.isLetter(line.charAt(i)) == true && i != endOfLine)
```

The second condition is always false as isWord is false, the statements under condition will never execute

```
   else if (Character.isLetter(line.charAt(i)) == false && isWord == true)
```

The third condition will never execute as this is same as first condition

```
    else if (Character.isLetter(line.charAt(i)) && i == endOfLine)
```

You need to change the conditions by turning on/off the 'isWord' flag when required.

Comment: OK, I thought I had it fixed with the simple addition of isWord=true; in this spot:
for (int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++) {
        if (Character.isLetter(line.charAt(i)) == true && i != endOfLine) {
            word.append(line.charAt(i));
            isWord=true;

I thought that would flip the flag to show we're on a word, until we get to a space in the string (the string is full of separate words and spaces inbetween) at which point we would go to the first else if statement,

Comment: at which point we would make the stringbuilder a string and add it to the hash set, then setting the isWord back to false. After the space there would be another letter for the next word, and we would start over in the first if statement for the loop.

Well, now when I run the test, I get a null pointer exception, and eclipse outlines the line: 

word.append(line.charAt(i));

right above the line I just added (isWord = true;)

What's wrong with my pointer for word?

Comment: @City17Mogul                                                                                 else if (Character.isLetter(line.charAt(i)) == false && isWord == true) {
            counter++;
            stringWord = word.toString();
            hashset.add(stringWord);
            ***** word = null; ******
            isWord = false;
        }        You are making 'word' to null in 2nd if statement and where are you re-initializing it.

Comment: I think it is not needed to make word to null. U can just use word.delete(0,word.length()).

Comment: I did some follow up with someone at work who's pretty handy with java, the problem was indeed setting the StringBuilder word to null. Doing so causes you to dereference word the next time the loop goes through and tries to use it, resulting in a null pointer exception. Instead of setting word to null, I simply create a new instance each time so instead of null it's word = new StringBuilder();

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach......

**-** Use `BreakIterator` from `java.text.BreakIterator` along with its `static getWordInstance()` method to get **hold of all the words in the sentence.**

**-** This will automatically handle the word or not thing....

**-** Then simply add it to the `HashSet<String>`

**See these links:**

http://javabeanz.wordpress.com/2009/02/21/working-with-text-in-java-using-breakiterator-api/

http://download.java.net/jdk7/archive/b123/docs/api/java/text/BreakIterator.html

http://www.javadocexamples.com/java/text/BreakIterator/getWordInstance%28Locale%20where%29.html

Comment: Im currently giving this a shot but I keep getting the message from eclipse cannot instantiate the type BreakIterator, even though I'm trying to do so like you would anything else. Suggestions?

Comment: @City17Mogul i hope you have done it this way... `BreakIterator br = BreakIterator.getWordInstance();`